# Textarea moving up when scrolling in BootStrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an problem in my application that i have developed in bootstrap.The problem is that i have a modal whose body max-height is setted. It contains a textarea,now when the tap on the textarea it gains the focus(correct till now) but when i scroll to down the text area which is in modal-body shown above the modal-header, it shows some type of duplicacy of textarea. But as soon as i stop the scrolling everything gone perfect again.

```
<div id="textPanel" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content"  style="padding-bottom: 5px">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Add/Edit Text</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-x: auto">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div id="textPreviewPanel" class="outer"
                         style="height: 60px;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-top: -15px">
                        <div class="inner" style="height: 100%">
                            <img id="textPreview" style="height: 100%;text-align: center"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    **<textarea id="addTextInput" ng-model="addEditTextModel" placeholder="Enter your text here"
                              rows="3"
                              class="form-control" style="resize: none"></textarea>**

                </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle to show your problem?

Comment: Please do not use inline styles, best practice is to use a separate CSS file

Comment: The problem is not because of using the inline styles. The problem is also on bootstrap own website when viewing in mobile browser